# route to edit view not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently attempting to view the index to one of my websites resources, and it is not able to find the edit route, no matter what I have tried. It keeps giving me:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :user_id=>nil, :id=>nil}
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Postname</th>
    <th>Postcontent</th>
    <th>Poster</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.postname %></td>
    <td><%= post.postcontent %></td>
    <td><%= post.poster %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_posts_path %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_post_path(@user,@post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_posts_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_user_post_path %>
```

controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

routes:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
```

rake routes output:

```
    user_posts GET    /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
               POST   /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
               PUT    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
               DELETE /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
         users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
          root        /                                        home#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you specify the params name on your route path like this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_post_path(:user_id => @user.id, :id => @post.id) %></td>
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you could accept the answer to help further users it would be nice.

Comment: I plan to, I have to wait :)